# How to Consume a Web Service in a .NET Class Project

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to create a class library .NET web project that encapsulates the functionality of consuming a web service.  I can create the .NET class web project and add a web service (Visual Studio 2005) but I cannot seem to figure out how to reference it.  It's easy to reference in a web site (simply address it by name), but apparently in the class library project things are different because I cannot figure out the namespace or reference name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Add Web Reference` tool in visual studio.  Enter the url of the webservice and it will be automatically loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you add your web reference, a client proxy would be generated. You would have to instantiate and wrap this proxy inside your class methods